# How to solve this using set theory?

Tags: combinatorics

Of the 38 people in my office, 10 like to drink chocolate, 15 are cricket fans, and 20 neither like chocolate nor like cricket. How many people like both cricket and chocolate?

Comment: Look up the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint*:

$$\text{ONLY CF $+$ ONLY DC $+$ BOTH $+$ NONE}=38$$

$$\text{ONLY DC $+$ BOTH}=10$$

$$\text{ONLY CF $+$ BOTH }=15$$

$$\text{NONE}=20$$

Four equations and four unknowns.